# how to add two row value and make one row in my sql

Tags: mysql

given table:

```
   id price1 price2 type  
    1  25      24     A
    2  42      44     B 
    3  59      54     C
    4  85      58     D
```

desire

```
id price1 price2 type  
1   67      68     A
3   59      54     C
4   85      58     D
```

please suggest me how to implement this because i have tried using Sum function but its not make sense  i am not able to fix it issue please help 
basically i have to add two row value and make type A .

Comment: Does here have any logic? Or just do the sum operation for first and second row?

Comment: Are you ok with some php code forthis?

Comment: I am not sure what you want? Can you clarify??

Comment: because  sick leave+casual leave will be casual leave due to some reason we have to display like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any visible logic here, is it just to make type `A + B` as type `A` and sum them?

If so use `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
SELECT min(t.id),SUM(t.price1),sum(t.price2),
       CASE WHEN t.type = 'B' THEN 'A' ELSE t.type END as type
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.type = 'B' THEN 'A' ELSE t.type END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT t1.id,(t1.price1+t2.price1) AS price1,
(t1.price2+t2.price2) AS price2,t1.type 
FROM table t1,table t2 WHERE t1.id%2=1 AND t2.id=t1.id+1;
```

Comment: I didnt checked for syntax errors, please check and tell me whether it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample result:

```
select id, sum(price1),SUM(price2),type from 
(select id,price1,price2,type from tbl_price ORDER BY id limit 2) as a

union all

select id,price1, price2,type FROM tbl_price where id >2
```

[image]